# Plotting Histogram using data from 2 numpy matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have 2 numpy matrices `A` and `B`:

- `A` matrix has as possible values only 1 or 0 (ON or OFF).
- `B` matrix has integers (min value -1).

I need to plot a histogram between the elements of matrix `B(X-axis)` and their frequency they are listed as ON in matrix `A` (in the corresponding positions).

For example:

```
IF A[1][1] and A[2][2] are 1, 
AND B[1][1] and B[2][2] are 2, 
THEN frequency of 2 should be 2 (similarly for each element of matrix B).
```

Basically for each element in `B`, its frequency increases by 1 if the corresponding element in `A` is `1`.

The matrices I am handling are huge (3992x3992). How do I do this as efficiently as possible?

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for us to work with.

Comment: It's much better to give example data (`A` and `B`) by writing a few lines of code than it is to describe your data in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in `B` where all small positive integers, you could simply do:

```
count = np.bincount(B.ravel())
tally = np.bincount(B.ravel(), weights=A.ravel())
freq = tally / count
```

But because you have negative numbers, it is probably best to play it safe and run `B` through `np.unique` first:

```
unq_val, unq_idx = np.unique(B.ravel(), return_inverse=True)
unq_count = np.bincount(unq_idx)
unq_tally = np.bincount(unq_idx, weights=A.ravel())
unq_freq = unq_tally / unq_count
```

When numpy 1.9 hits the street in the next few weeks, you can get an extra performance edge by joining the first two lines in the single one:

```
unq_val, unq_idx, unq_count = np.unique(B.ravel(), return_inverse=True,
                                        return_counts=True)
```

After that, you will have you `x` values in `unq_val` and the corresponding `y` values in `unq_freq`. On my system, with this made up data:

```
A = np.random.randint(2, size=(3992, 3992))
B = np.random.randint(50, size=(3992, 3992))
```

The whole thing runs in 0.3 sec without passing it through unique, and in a little over 6 sec when using it.

Comment: After this to plot histogram I use unq_val and ung_freq in matplotlib?